# How to associate posts to users if posts are already associated to another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im on rails 4. Im creating a wine review app and I have three models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end

class Wine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wine
end
```

As of now I have my review form like this

```
<%= form_for [@wine, @review] do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

This associates the new review with the wine being reviewed. How would I make it so when I create a new review, it associates the current_user with the review as well? I don't need the wine to be associated with the user, just the review so I can display who reviewed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the controller update/create method before saving the review

```
@review.user = current_user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the build method in the controller, which would let you do the following:

```
@review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)
```

Comment: I'm already using @review = @wine.reviews.build(params[:review]) to associate it with the wine, how would I add the user as well?

Comment: If you want then add one extra line @review.user_id =current_user.id